# How can Wordpress to authenticate a user in a existing application?

Tags: wordpress, authentication

My new project is enhancing web application based on NodeJs and angular2.
New features required bbs and posts.
So I decided to use wordpress.

I want to integrate wordpress and existing application seamlessly.
Exising app entirely handle user data, and wordpress use it.
So I should make wp_authenticate filter.

My ideas are below.

```
  1. sign up(New User):     
   a. Existing application(A) create use information.  (A's User Table) 
   b. A invoke wordpress to create new use
 data.  (Wordpress's wp_users table)

  2. sign in(Existing User):
    a. authenticate with A. (A's user table)
    b. create wp_coockie to make login-in status. 
  3. delete user:
    a. delete from A's.
    b. delete from wordpress's.
```

Is my plan is correct?
If you know best practice for this case, could you please share it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it.
Existing external-db-auth (https://ko.wordpress.org/plugins/external-db-auth-reloaded/) was helpful.

My resolution was as below.

1. setup external-db-auth plugin
2. login by above plugin
3. I modified plugin for save php session information to browser's local storage.
4. In angular side, angular read session information from local storage.

Hope to help someone.